# Apache mod_rewrite rewrite everything but files in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following RewriteRule redirects every request to bootstrap.php except the filextenstions between the parentheses

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|pdf|doc|txt|htm|html|xml|ttf|flv|swf|xml|ics|htc)$ bootstrap.php
```

Is it possible to exclude **ALL** files witouth declaring them like above?

So all requests should redirect to boostrap.php if the request is not a file

Comment: move to webmasters or serverfault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should check the file whether or not exists and is a regular file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) bootstrap.php [L]
```

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question. Thanks for answering it :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with that, every file with 4 letter extension would not head to bootstrap.php

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule !\.[\d]{4}$ bootstrap.php
```